# How to redirect search result page to post

Tags: search, redirect

I'd like to redirect a search result page URL to a specific post. I've tried doing a 301 redirect in the .htaccess but it is not working.

As an example:

I want to redirect permanently the URL http://www.domain.com/?s=keyword to http://www.domain.com/name-of-the-post.html

Is possible to do this in the .htaccess file'

Best

Carles

Answer (score 7):

I think it is better that you do this inside the WordPress install, not on the .htaccess. Is not easy to maintain and maybe a problem, if you have more results for a search. You can use the follow source, write in a small plugin and activate. If the search result have only one result, then will rewrite to the single post.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_single_result' );
function fb_single_result() {

    if (is_search()) {
        global $wp_query;

        if ( 1 === $wp_query->post_count ) {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $wp_query->posts['0']->ID ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I want is to redirect some of my result page URLs to specific posts URLs. Is not an issue of having just 1 result for the search.

Comment: Don't forget to exit (or die) after a [wp_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).