# Redirect to custom post if custom archive page has just one result?

Tags: posts, redirect, archives, customization

So i have made a Custom Post Type called cars and 4 taxonomies that i use to make/edit the cars pages. I have a search&filter pro plug-in to help me sort my pages by the 4 taxonomies assigned. It gives me results on the custom archive page i made, using a grid and the search and filter plug-in. My problem is i want the archive to be redirected to the post page of the car if we have only one result in the search archive.

But i need it adapted to custom post types. Can anyone help !?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect search result page to post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128577/how-to-redirect-search-result-page-to-post)

Comment: Welcome aboard. I flagged this post as duplicate because the portal has similar or answered content based on your question. Please search first, then ask your question.

Comment: @SerkanAlgur that maybe works for normal page post types archives. I need the code for custom post types to be counted in the archive.